# Why were there so many portals in Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In the "Portals" scene, I counted about 17 portals, which seems way too much for all the people who came:

- 1 for Wakanda fighters (Black Panther, Bucky, Falcon, etc.)
- 1 for Titan planet (Doctor Strange, Spiderman, Star Lord, etc.)
- 1 for the Wasp
- 1 for the Asgardians
- 3 for the 3 sanctums (Hong Kong, New York, London)
- 1 for the Ravagers
- 1 for Pepper Potts

That's only 9 portals, so where do the other 8 lead to? There is a chance that Wakanda had more than 1 portal (Even though we see basically the whole army come out from behind Black Panther- Watch [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fP2w_UAK6B4) at 1:30 minutes).

[image]

Comment: there seem to be various ships emerging from the other ones

Comment: ummm.... *Dramatic effect?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've counted up 9 portals, there's only 8 of those actually on the ground. The rest are in the air for the Wakandan/Ravager ships to come through, which we see in the image in the question. The closer "air portals" are for the Wakandan ships and the further away ones appear to have the Ravagers coming out of them.

Comment: So 8 different portals for a few ships?

Comment: @MBEllis Easier to use multiple smaller portals to get the ships in place than to form a  queue through less of them.